# Finite mapping $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology

Is there an continous function $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that $f^{-1}(a)$ is finite for every $a \in \mathbb R$?

It's not possible for analytic or smooth but I'm curious about continous mapping.

Comment: Hint: Would the preimage of $\mathbb{R}$ (or the image of $f$) minus a point be connected?  Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think it is true if $f$ is even differentiable, by the implicit function theorem.

Comment: Take two points where $f$ differs. Can you draw infinitely many paths between them, disjoint except for the endpoints? (Then use IVT)

Comment: @MichaelBurr Why should the preimage of a connected set be connected ? For example, if I take $X$ disconnected and $f:X \to \mathbb R$ a constant map, the preimage of $\{f(x)\}$ is not connected.

Comment: @Meelo : very elegant, thanks !

Comment: @N.H. While you're technically correct, I think you're missing his point. We want the preimage of a _disconnected_ set. Those are usually also disconnected, as long as the function is continuous. And a disconnected subset of $\Bbb R^2$ must have infinite complement.

Comment: @Arthur : thanks I should go to sleep...

Comment: @A.P. Without continuity, it is only a question of cardinality. Then, since all $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$ have the same cardinality, you can even find bijections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take any continuous map $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$. Suppose for contradiction that $f$ has finite fibers...

Choose two points $a,b \in f(\Bbb R^2)$ with $a < b$. We can do this because $f$ is non-constant, otherwise it cannot have finite fibers.

Pick a point $c \in (a,b)$. Then the set $A:=\Bbb R^2 \backslash \;f^{-1}(\{c\})$ is connected, since its complement is finite.

Thus $f(A)$ is a connected subset of $\Bbb R$. Since $a,b \in f(A)$ and since $c \in (a,b)$, it follows that $c \in f(A)$. But this contradicts the definition of $A$.

Comment: This is exactly the answer of Michael Burr.

Comment: @N.H. Yes, I just thought it would be a good idea to write it explicitly. You don't have to accept it if you don't want to...

Comment: @N.H. Michael Burr's was a comment, which he chose not to write as an answer. Writing actual answers (and upvoting and/or accepting them) is important not just because of the reputation gain (which some users don't care about), but also because it removes questions from the list of unanswered questions, which contributes to keeping the system tidy.

Comment: @A.P. I understood. But I don't think it's very fair attitude (as your of deleting your comment btw). Anyway, I will accept this answer for keep the system tidy :-)

Comment: @N.H. I deleted my comment because it was no longer relevant and the conversation in the comments to your question was already long enough. I agree, though, that it is usually better to ask the commenter to post an answer him/herself, and only post one yourself if they decline to do so. Expanding on a terse comment like in this case, though, falls in a grey area: many users opt to writing those because they are uninterested in or don't have time to write a full-fledged answer.

Comment: @A.P. first I hope you didn't take it personnally, I didn't mean to be rude or agressive. Now I will stop here because the comments will become too longs, and as I understood it's better to keep them short :)

Comment: Okay then; this is the last time I'll try to expand on someone's comment I guess...

Comment: @Shalop : As I said I didn't mean to be rude and I probably don't get all the implicit rules of MSE.

Comment: @N.H. No problem. I didn't mean it that way. I apologize if that comment sounded aggressive. :)