# Is there a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ whose all level sets are finite?

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-topology, continuity

Is there a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that every  $f^{-1} (c)$ is either the  empty set or a finite set?

This is discussed in the comments of the following post.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265177/a-generalization-of-the-borsuk-ulam-theorem

Answer (score 0):

I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346366/finite-mapping-f-mathbb-r2-to-mathbb-r) the same question for a map $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$. I believe one can adapt the answer : the image is connected and it is not a point, so we can assume it contains a disk. Take $C$ a circle in this disk, and $x,y$ in this disk but separed by $C$.

By hypothesis, $C' := f^{-1}(C)$ should be homeomorphic to a finite union of circles so it can't disconnect $\mathbb R^3$. Now, $f(\mathbb R^3 \backslash C')$ is not connected since it is contained in $\mathbb R^2 \backslash C$ and intersect both interior and exterior by hypothesis.

Comment: @downvoter : could I have some explanations ?

Comment: As an uovoter I thank you for  your  answer  but could  you  please explain why the  pre image  is  a  finite  union of  circles?

Comment: @AliTaghavi : I am not so sure, but I believe that $f$ can be "approximated" by a polynomial map, or anything which is differentiable and when we can use implicit function theorem. And then there is at least a point $p$ where the derivative does not vanish in a little neighborhood. By implicit function theorem, we pick all the possible inverse which should exists locally, and take a circle small enough for be contained in all the open where this inverse are defined. Of course this is certainly not true for all $f$ but it should work by using that $f$ is uniformly continuous on a compact ...

Comment: ... so by Weierstrass approximation theorem there is a sequence of polynomial which converge uniformly to $f$. But this is a very weak argument.